# PHP and 2 multidimensional array compare based on two key values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two multidimensional arrays like this:

```
$original = Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [time] => 1364690340
        [memberid] => 90
        [type] => single
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [time] => 1364690341
        [memberid] => 92
        [type] => fixed
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [time] => 1364690342
        [memberid] => 96
        [type] => single
    )
)
```

and second one like this

```
$new = Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [time] => 1364825750
        [memberid] => 90
        [type] => single
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [time] => 1364825751
        [memberid] => 92
        [type] => single
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [time] => 1364825752
        [memberid] => 96
        [type] => single
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [time] => 1364825753
        [memberid] => 111
        [type] => single
    )
)
```

My problem is: I want to search $original array for matches based on memberid and type keys and if memberid and type ARE NOT the same -> I want to remove that array from $original array. So in this case I want to keep [0] Array and [2] Array as in $new array I have same memberid and same type as in original, but I would want to remove [1] Array as memberid is the same, but type is different. So my final $original array will look like this:

```
$original = Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [time] => 1364690340
        [memberid] => 90
        [type] => single
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [time] => 1364690342
        [memberid] => 96
        [type] => single
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, just tested it and it works as expected.

```
// Presuming your two arrays are still called $new & $original
$original = array(); // your data
$new = array(); // your data

$newArray = array();
foreach($original AS $key => $val){
    $newArray[$val['memberid'] . '-' . $val['type']] = $val;
}

$original = array();
foreach($new AS $key => $val){
    if(isset($newArray[$val['memberid'] . '-' . $val['type']])){
        $original[] = $newArray[$val['memberid'] . '-' . $val['type']];
    }
}

print_r($original);
```

Answer (score -1):

Without making any assumptions about your data, here's an inefficient solution, O(*m* * *n*) if *m* and *n* are the lengths of your arrays:

```
$new_original = array();
foreach ($original as $elem) {
  // let's see if $new has something with the same type and memberid
  foreach ($new as $candidate) {
    if ($candidate['type'] == $elem['type'] &&
        $candidate['memberid'] == $elem['memberid']) {
      // it does! let's keep $elem
      $new_original[] = $elem;
    }
  }
}

// reassign it to $original if desired
$original = $new_original;
```

However, it would be much cooler to do more efficient lookups. For example, if we can assume there is at most one element with a given memberid in `$new`:

```
// turn $new into a map
$new_as_map = array();
foreach ($new as $candidate) {
  $new_as_map[$candidate['memberid']] = $candidate;
}

$new_original = array();
foreach ($original as $elem) {
  if (isset($new_as_map[$elem['memberid']])) {
    $candidate = $new_as_map[$elem['memberid']];
    if ($candidate['type'] == $elem['type']) {
      $new_original[] = $elem;
    }
  }
}

// reassign it to $original if desired
$original = $new_original;
```